# MVC: Access data attributes in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Might be a asked and answered...sorry but, I've been searching for a while.

RAZOR VIEW

```
@foreach (var item in Model.LanguageList)
{
    <li>
    <a href="@Url.Action("ChangeLanguage", "UserHeader")"  data_languageID="@item.LanguageID" data_someval="hello" data_somevalb="world">
       <div class="flag @item.LanguageFlag">
       </div>
       <div class="flag-title"> @item.LanguageName</div>
    </a>
    </li>
}
```

How do I access the data attributes in my controller?

CONTROLLER

```
    public ActionResult ChangeLanguage()
    {
        var x =  ControllerContext; //// ??? get the collection of [data-xx] from where?

        return RedirectToAction("Buttons", "Designer");
    }
```

Comment: You need to POST a model into a controller, or GET it with parameters.

Comment: Your cant. You need to pass the values as query string parameters and add those parameters to your GET method.

Comment: So to be clear:  The only way I can access my [data-xxx] is using javascript/jquery.

Comment: Yes. Its not clear exactly what you wanting to do by adding `data-*` attributes, but if you wanting to pass those values to the `ChangeLanguage()` method, then it needs to be `<a href="@Url.Action("ChangeLanguage", "UserHeader", new { languageID = item.LanguageID, someval = "hello", ...etc })", ...>` and the method needs to be `ChangeLanguage(int languageID, string someval, ...etc )`

Comment: Thanks...that was the clarity I needed.   Appreciated :)

Comment: sorry I am still trying to figure out how to accept.  Thanks for the help...sorry for the delay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data-*` attributes are client side values and are not sent in the request.

In order to send those values, add them as route values

```
@foreach (var item in Model.LanguageList)
{
  <li>
    <a href="@Url.Action("ChangeLanguage", "UserHeader", new { languageID=item.LanguageID, someval="hello", somevalb="world" })">
      <div class="flag @item.LanguageFlag"></div>
      <div class="flag-title"> @item.LanguageName</div>
    </a>
  </li>
}
```

and include parameters in your GET method for the values

```
public ActionResult ChangeLanguage(int LanguageID, string someval, string somevalb)
```

Alternatively you could handle this using javascript/jquery (the `ChangeLanguage()` method also needs to be modified as shown above)

```
$('a').click(function() {
  // get the url
  var url = $(this).attr('href');
  // get the data attributes
  var languageID = $(this).data('languageID');
  var someVal= $(this).data('someval');
  var someValB= $(this).data('somevalb');
  location.href = url + '?languageID=' + languageID + '&someVal =' + someVal + '&someValB=' + someValB;
  return false; // cancel the default redirect
});
```